# Passing props to state in top level component

Tags: reactjs, components, state, react-props

I'm trying to pass props using the handleUpdate function in my child component to my top level component and update the state with those props values. So far, I don't see the props appearing when I console log. I don't think I'm passing the correct arguments. I've tinkered around and am stuck. Can someone assist and explain their reasoning?

handleUpdate function in child component:

```
search = async (word) => {

        try{
            // var word = this.state.word.trim();
            const data = await MerriamAPI.getWordInfo(word);
            
            if (data){
                this.props.handleUpdate({
                    word: word,
                    info: data,
                    versions: data[0].meta.stems,
                    shortdef: data[0].shortdef[0],
                    partOfSpeech: data[0].fl,
                    pronunciation: data[0].hwi.prs[0].mw, 
                }, 
            }
            else{
                console.log('No Definition Found')
            }
        }
        catch{
            this.setState({error: 'No Definition Found'})
        }
        console.log(this.props)
    }
```

Parent component:

```
class App extends Component {

  state = {
    redirect: {},
    word: '',
    error: '',
    info: [],
    partOfSpeech: [],
    versions: [],
    shortdef: "",
    pronunciation: "",
  }
  

  setRedirect = redirect =>
    this.setState({redirect})


  handleUpdate = (props) => 
    this.setState({word:this.props})


render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Route 
          render={ routeProps => <Redirector redirect={this.state.redirect} setRedirect={this.setRedirect} {...routeProps} />}
        />
        <header>
          <nav>
            <Link to='/'>My Dictionary</Link>
          </nav>
        </header>

        <main>
        <Route
            render = { routeProps =>
              !routeProps.location.state?.alert ? '' :
              <div>
                { routeProps.location.state.alert }
              </div>
            }
          />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" render={ routeProps => <Home handleUpdate={this.handleUpdate} {...routeProps} />} />
            <Route exact path="/definition/:word" render={ routeProps => <GetWordContainer word={this.state.word} {...routeProps} />} />
          </Switch>
        </main>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I can decipher your partial snippets, it seems `handleUpdate` in `App` is access the wrong "props" object, i.e. `this.props` of `App` instead of the passed `props` argument to the function.

## Solution

Change the function parameter to something other than "props" to remove confusion, `word` is a great choice that allows you to also use object shorthand assignment.

```
handleUpdate = word => this.setState({ word });
```

Based on the object shape you pass to `handleUpdate` and your state object, I'm going to guess that you more likely want to spread in the object versus assigning it all to `this.state.word`

```
handleUpdate = values => this.setState({ ...values });
```